# Actualizar datos de base sql sin recargar la pagina

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una duda: Quiero actualizar los datos que se ven en mi web php que está conectada a una base de datos(**Los datos los modifico yo desde la base**) y que lo que cambie en la base de datos se actualice en la web sin actualizar. **Se** que se hace con "Ajax" pero los unicos tutoriales que encontré son con formularios, y no se adaptarlo o no me sirve.

Acá dejo en lo que quiero que se aplique: Que se refresque lo de "partido1" sin actualizar la página (Todo esto está dentro de PHP)

```html
    else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 11 <= $hora && $hora <= 12) {
        echo '<h3>Estás mirando: ' . $rows_dbpartidos['partido1'] . '</h3>';
    }
```

Comment: ¿No hiciste esta misma pregunta ayer?

Comment: Si quieres añadir nueva información o más datos a una pregunta que ya hiciste, edita la pregunta original en lugar de crear una pregunta nueva. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información.